# Is there a shorthand name for Windows 8 app development?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have to make an application for Windows 8 tablets, and the biggest problem I have at the moment is I'm not sure how to phrase searches when looking for information.

For example, with Android and iOS, you can just google stuff like "Android implementing listview" or "iOS implementing listview". When I'm googling for information on creating apps on Windows 8 devices, is all I can do search "Windows 8 implementing listview". It's just when I do this, a lot of the time I come up short, or get results just pointing me to applications on the store.

Thanks for any information on this

Answer (score 2):

`wp` is a pretty common abbreviation for Windows Phone.

Searching for [wp 8 listview](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp%208%20listview&oq=wp%208%20listview&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.2718j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) seems to give good, relevant results.

Comment: Careful not to confuse with WordPress, also commonly abbreviated as `wp`.

Comment: So can I assume that if I search for windows phone, the information will be relevant to Windows 8 devices such as phones and tablets?

Comment: @AndyOHart Searching for `wp 8` would give you relevant information. Usually, you'll be able to tell if you've got the right information within a few seconds of opening any resulting link.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but Windows Phone != Windows Tablet. I think the OP is asking about the latter.

Answer (score 0):

`WinRT` does the job quite well in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

*WinRT*, *Metro*, or not really shorter is *Windows 8 Store App*.  These eventually gave way to *UWA* or *Universal Windows App*.